# How do I insert PHP before and after HTML code from an external PHP sheet? (Wrap a div with PHP)

Tags: php

Here is my issue, I have an assortment of PHP files that creates a certain theme for my website.  I have created what you could call a child theme that uses the PHP framework from that parent theme but with an alternate CSS and a kind of functions.php.  Within the parent theme's PHP there is HTML to create assorted `<div>`s.  What I need is to use the child's functions.php to wrap a block of `<div>`s from the parent's PHP/HTML with a `<div>` that has a custom id and class.  In other words, I want to wrap HTML in a `<div>` using an external PHP sheet - before the `<div>` opens and after it closes.

Is there a PHP function that can do this?

I cannot edit the parent theme PHP, and I cannot just copy and paste the code from the parent to the child due to parent theme having upgrading capabilities.
For reference, here is the block of PHP from the parent file.  I want to wrap the `<div id="footer">` with a `<div>` with an id of "footer-wrapper".

```
<!-- footer -->
        <div id="footer"<?php $this->html( 'userlangattributes' ) ?>>
            <?php foreach( $this->getFooterLinks() as $category => $links ): ?>
                <ul id="footer-<?php echo $category ?>">
                    <?php foreach( $links as $link ): ?>
                        <li id="footer-<?php echo $category ?>-<?php echo $link ?>"><?php $this->html( $link ) ?></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php $footericons = $this->getFooterIcons("icononly");
            if ( count( $footericons ) > 0 ): ?>
                <ul id="footer-icons" class="noprint">
<?php           foreach ( $footericons as $blockName => $footerIcons ): ?>
                    <li id="footer-<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $blockName ); ?>ico">
<?php               foreach ( $footerIcons as $icon ): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->skin->makeFooterIcon( $icon ); ?>

<?php               endforeach; ?>
                    </li>
<?php           endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /footer -->
```

Comment: Can't you just add `<div id="footer-wrapper">` to the reference file above?

Comment: No, I cannot add code to the parent.php because it is frequently updated from servers.  I also cannot simply copy and paste this block to the child.php.  I do think that your comment was unneeded and uneducated as it was not anywhere near the response that was assumed based on the question - feel free to try again.

Comment: Feel free to rethink your question and ask again! In no way was my question condescending or out of line. It was simply a question. If you want help from people, ask coherent questions.

Comment: This will be the end of my comments to you:

I asked, "Is there a PHP function that can do this?"
I did not ask, "What HTML can I put inside of this parent.php file?" 

You resorted to giving me an elementary response that avoided my primary question as you failed to answer with a PHP function.

Comment: "Is there a PHP function that can do this?" Uh, yeah. There are a ton of functions that magically solve the coding mess you've created.

Answer (score 0):

in child_theme.php

```
echo '<div id="footer-wrapper">';
include('parent_theme_footer_block.php');
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: I understand what you are intending by the two "echo" lines, but could you explain and expand on the second line?  Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing more about your application structure, this is about as easy I can get. Check out this [http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for an explanation on include